# Resizing and moving win 10 partitions to a debian box

Tags: linux, debian, partition, grub2, move-partition

Context:

After replacing a win 10 hdd with an ssd that runs debian 11, how can the partitions from
the hdd be copied over to the ssd so that win 10 is bootable?

```
# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0   500M  0 part 
├─sda2        8:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─sda3        8:3    0  57.7G  0 part /media/sebi/423494AC3494A487
├─sda4        8:4    0   881M  0 part 
├─sda5        8:5    0 488.3G  0 part /media/sebi/New Volume
├─sda6        8:6    0   3.8G  0 part 
├─sda7        8:7    0  28.6G  0 part /media/sebi/39d7f984-f73c-40bb-b51f-a2382c56ef37
├─sda8        8:8    0 238.4G  0 part /media/sebi/0ee6e718-ee27-4bb7-8f74-ea1e89885b3d
├─sda9        8:9    0 112.8G  0 part /media/sebi/2826BEFD26BECB58
└─sda10       8:10   0   538M  0 part 
sdb           8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk 
└─sdb1        8:17   0   1.8T  0 part /media/sebi/Expansion Drive
nvme0n1     259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   476M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 325.9G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0  18.6G  0 part [SWAP]
```

`sda` is the hdd with win, `sdb` is an external drive, `nvme0n1` the debian drive (currently booted).

Stuff tried:

Since both drives are 1 TB in size, the initial approach was to move the win partitions to the ssd using clonezilla, move `sda3`, `sda7` and `sda8` to the left in gparted, so that they are next to one another, delete, and merge the unallocated partitions into a single partition where debian would be installed.

Every time gparted moves, shrinks or extends a partition renders the drive unbootable (regardless whether it's win or linux).

Current goal is to move all sdas except, `sda1`, `sda7` and `sda8` (which were not used by win) to `nvme0n1` and create a setup that allows dual booting of both win and deb.

What steps should be taken after copying (`dd`-ing) the `sda`s to `nvme0n1`?

Comment: Since you are using UEFI, the Windows bootloader and GRUB will be easily able to coexist on `nvme0n1p1`. You would need to update the UEFI NVRAM boot variables to point to correct partitions for each OS. In Linux, `efibootmgr` would be a good tool for this task. But rebuilding the Windows bootloader's BCD registry to match the new configuration, and reconfiguring Windows so it will recognize the new location of its system partition would be the more important part of your task; however, it is off topic for **Unix & Linux** StackExchange. You should ask this in SuperUser.SE instead.

Comment: Changing Windows boot from MBR to EFI is not trivial at all.

Comment: @Artem S. Tashkinov do you have any pointers?

Comment: Actually it looks to be easy if you have bootable media (USB flash with Windows installation files must suffice): https://www.windowscentral.com/how-convert-mbr-disk-gpt-move-bios-uefi-windows-10